# postgresql Large Join is not using indexes

Tags: postgresql-performance

I have a large table join on the keys that does not use the index.

[Query and plan here](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/15a6a91492g8g935#plan/node/5) :  https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/15a6a91492g8g935#plan/node/5

Both tables have an index on the key, like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "stage_fact_revenue_900_idx_a" ON "stage"."stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims" USING BTREE ("date","billed_relation_id","subject_client_id","identifier","revenue_type");
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "fact_revenue_idx_a" ON "star"."fact_revenue" USING BTREE ("date","identifier","billed_relation_id","subject_client_id","revenue_type");
```

but the index is not used (see query plan).

Any clues why this is not happening? The largest steps are sorts, can I pre-sort the tables to prevent this?

Comment: Answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/327141/can-sorting-in-postgresql-explain-plan-be-prevented/327170#327170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer came from [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/327141/can-sorting-in-postgresql-explain-plan-be-prevented/327170#327170) :

In the end, I found out that the main time absorber was something else: the query was used to insert data into a table, and that table contained 17 indexes..... Pruning the number of indexes was the best performance gain.