# Can sorting in postgresql EXPLAIN plan be prevented?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, explain

I have a large table join on the keys. The explain plan shows that most of the time is spent on sorting.

Is there anything I can do to prevent the large sort steps? Can I pre-sort the table?

Query and plan here : https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/15a6a91492g8g935#plan/node/5

Both tables already have an index on the key, like this, but that index does not seem to be used:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "stage_fact_revenue_900_idx_a" ON "stage"."stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims" USING BTREE ("date","billed_relation_id","subject_client_id","identifier","revenue_type");
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "fact_revenue_idx_a" ON "star"."fact_revenue" USING BTREE ("date","identifier","billed_relation_id","subject_client_id","revenue_type");
```

Comment: Could you please provide the DDL of the relevant tables and the EXPLAIN plan (as text). I think you require more indexes, but it's difficult to tell without further info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An index speeds up the search if the returned rows are not more than roughly 10%, otherwise a full scan of the table is faster.

Postgresql chooses a full scan for `stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims` because it needs to select all rows and it needs columns not present in the index.
For the same reason, it thinks that it's better to scan `fact_revenue` once and sort the results rather than doing 177 millions index seeks.

Some things you could try:

1. Add to your query an explicit `ORDER BY date, identifier, billed_relation_id, subject_client_id, revenue_type` this should suggest to Postgres that using the index on `fact_revenue` could avoid  the sort.
2. Change the first index to have the same fields order of the second (or add a new index in that order). At present they have the same fields but in different orders, so only one of them can actually be used to avoid the sort.
3. Try rewriting the query using NOT EXISTS instead of a LEFT JOIN:

Like this:

```
select
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.date as date,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.dim_date_key as dim_date_key,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.identifier as identifier,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.revenue_type as revenue_type,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.product_id as product_id,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.dim_product_key as dim_product_key,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.billing_partner_id as billing_partner_id,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.dim_billing_partner_key as dim_billing_partner_key,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.billed_relation_id as billed_relation_id,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.subject_client_id as subject_client_id,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.dim_subject_client_key as dim_subject_client_key,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.client_id as client_id,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.dim_billed_client_key as dim_billed_client_key,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.partner_id as partner_id,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.dim_billed_partner_key as dim_billed_partner_key,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.price as price,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.duration as duration,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.amount as amount,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.leaf as leaf,
    stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.dss_record_source as dss_record_source,
    current_timestamp as dss_create_time,
    current_timestamp as dss_update_time
from
    stage.stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims
    
where
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM star.fact_revenue fact_revenue WHERE stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.date = fact_revenue.date
    and stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.identifier = fact_revenue.identifier
    and stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.revenue_type = fact_revenue.revenue_type
    and stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.billed_relation_id = fact_revenue.billed_relation_id
    and stage_fact_revenue_900_add_dims.subject_client_id = fact_revenue.subject_client_id)
ORDER BY date, identifier, billed_relation_id, subject_client_id, revenue_type;
```

Comment: Hi @andrea-b, thank you or your extensive answer. I tried all things. resulted in a relatively small gain. In the end I found out that the main time absorber was something else: the query was used to insert data into a table, and that table contained 17 indexes..... Pruning the amount of indexes was the best performance gain.